# WebRTC Vuejs but Video not displaying

Tags: vue.js, webrtc

I have tried many ways to deal with this, but I still couldn't make the video appear to the ref="me".

```html
<template>
    <div class="room">
        <div class="people" id="people">
            <div class="person">
                <div class="person__video">
                    <video ref="me"></video>
                </div>

                <div class="person__name">
                    {{room}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Index",
        props:['room'],

        mounted() {
            window.webrtc.joinRoom(this.room);

            window.webrtc.on('localStream', (stream) => {
                let attachMediaStream = require('attachmediastream');

                attachMediaStream(stream, this.$refs.me, {
                    autoplay: true,
                    mirror: true,
                    muted: true
                })
            })
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
'enableAudio' boolean   true    enables audio on join
'enableVideo' boolean   true    enables video on join
```

Comment: Could you please tell exactly how to add them in the code?

Comment: like you added `autoplay` and `mirror`, try in the same way